# Is there a hands free way to manipulate pandora while driving?

Tags: user-interface, driving-mode

I was wondering if anyone knew of a handsfree way to manipulate pandora while driving.

(On Linux, there is an app available known as PianoBar, which is open source and can interact with Pandora servers without using an official client; this includes BASH integration, which allows you to....)

Well, that's neither here nor there, I'm in engineering school and I hardly have time to program any apps.

I have a Galaxy S4, and what I really want is a way to manipulate Pandora Radio while driving.  (They don't seem to have an disabled accessibility, either >.<)  It certainly does not have to be complete, but it should at least let me like and dislike songs without using my hands.

I'm really just looking for a way to listen to my music without having to look away from the road.

I've tried S-voice, and it can start Pandora, but after that you appear to be on your own..

Thanks for any help!

PS: Assume I have no more than an aux jack to use in the car, so the answer can't be "install something"... it's an integrated head unit.

Answer (score 0):

This would really have to be enabled by the developers of the app, unfortunately. An always listening app would be very risky to distribute, as it would generate many complaints about battery life...

I have an Android Wear watch, which makes interaction minimal and on your wrist as you drive. This is my best suggestion, though this also would depend on the developers, if they have implemented Wear functionality.

I know this is a more costly solution than an app, but there's more to it than just this functionality. Wear apps can also implement voice functionality, so those developers better get working...